# Linux, How to delete a folder with more than 1 million files?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, rm

I'm working on a website for a client, and I just see a folder containing more than 1 million cache files.

I need to delete him, but i can't, i have this message : Argument list too long

I started to delete all files starting with aaa*, bbb*, ccc* .... but I do not want to spend my life... `(rm -f aaa*.string.php)`

How can i do that ?? Thanks !

Comment: try `find /directory/path -type f -delete`

Comment: See [Perl to the rescue: case study of deleting a large directory](http://blogs.perl.org/users/randal_l_schwartz/2011/03/perl-to-the-rescue-case-study-of-deleting-a-large-directory.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` and `xargs` are your friends, as always:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Or, for the special case of deletion (thanks, Eddy_Em):

```
find -type f -delete
```

Comment: The first command is hardly any better than `rm *`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Yes, it is, because `xargs` is aware of command line length limitations and calls rm more than once.

Comment: Seems like I underestimated `xargs`, thanks for the info and +1 :)

Comment: How can i know if this command is working well ? I don't want to wait 4 hours for nothing^^

Comment: BTW there is another (not right, but available) way: unlink directory (without unlinking files) and run fsck. I didn't try its running time, but some people said, that it's even could be much less than `find … -delete` on some filesystems.

Comment: @Clément Andraud: Either slap a `-v` on the `rm` command (but this will print an _enormous_ amount of data if there are as many files as you say, and actually slow the process down considerably), or execute e.g. `watch -n 10 'du -ms directory'` in another shell and see the file size going down.

Comment: GNU find has the `-exec +` switch which makes the `xargs` pipe unnecessary. E.g. `find dir -type f -exec rm {} +` will also minimize process invocations in the same way as `xargs`, but the piping isn't needed. As compared to `-delete`, this will enable switches to be added to `rm`, just as with `xargs`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing the individual files, you could remove and then re-create the folder itself:

```
cd folder/..
rm -rf folder
mkdir folder
```

If this works in your scenario, this will probably be much faster than any method based on explicitly enumerating and removing the individual files.

Comment: Hum ok, Your solution killed my server ^^

Comment: I'll wait a bit for the command to stop

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ls | xargs -n 200 rm -f
```

Will eventually remove everything

You can use `grep` to do pattern matching if you want to delete a subset of the files

Comment: Be careful when piping into xargs, it will happily interpret spaces as delimiters. Have a space in your filename, and have neverending fun. Standard pattern is `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: this will be slower than `find` and won't work for files with spaces or new lines in their names. See [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)